# Как использовать словари с потоками?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Есть несколько потоков, задача которых получать входные данные из **одного большого словаря**, и записывать **измененные** данные в другой **глобальный** словарь. При этом каждый поток работает со **своей частью первого большого словаря**. Проблема заключается в том, что после завершения работы этих двух потоков оказывается, что длинна второго словаря меньше чем у первого, откуда потоки берут данные! Т.е потоки почему то не записывают данные во второй словарь, при этом не возникает ошибок.

```
from threading import RLock, Thread

lock = RLock()
first_big_dict = { some_elements }
second_big_dict = {}

def thread_func(array):
    with lock:
         item_name = getting_item_name()
         item_value = getting_item_value()

    do_something()

    with lock:
        second_big_dict[item_name] = item_value

thread1 = Thread(target=thread_func, args=(piece_of_first_big_dict,))
thread2 = Thread(target=thread_func, args=(second_piece_of_big_dict,))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Я работаю с **CPython** и примерно так выглядит мой код. Я использую **lock чтобы останавливать другие потоки на время записи в глобальный словарь** по информации из интернета, но это также не помогло. Как использовать глобальные словари с многопоточностью и как можно исправить мою проблему?

Comment: do_something() изменяет item_name ?  если имена одинаковыми выйдут, то данные перезапишутся и длинна уменьшится.do_something() нужно смотреть.

Comment: Из этого кода не видно вообще будут ли все элементы в первом словаре обработаны. Покажите как работает `getting_item_name`. И еще: взаимодействует ли с `first_big_dict` `do_something`? Как используется `array`? Как формируются аргументы к `thread_func`. Похоже, что вы при упрощении кода потеряли важные для вопроса моменты

Comment: Нужно больше кода. В имеющемся коде вроде бы проблем нет, надо больше деталей.